# Enable Remote Desktops Recent Connection List (jump list)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, jumplist

I would like to enable the remote desktop recent connection list. In Windows 7 this is referred to as a "jump list". I seen many Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 Remote Desktop icons work. You can right click on the taskbar button and get a recent list of all known connections.

However on my new machine this does not work. How do you enable this feature?

Comment: Do other programs Jump list work correctly or is it isolated on Windows RDP? You could start by checking whether Jump List is enabled by right-clicking taskbar -> `Properties` then switch to `Jump List` tab.

Comment: I forget this issue still was unanswered. I had figure it out and it's like Arya S. had said in another comment. I had disabled the Jump List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the issue. The issue was that I had turned off "Store Recently Opened Programs" and "Store and display recently opened items in Jump List". If you disable these then the remote desktop history will turn off. It's a no brainer but I did not put the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Information from threads on [Technet's support forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/58c12e12-09cf-4eba-9890-270deb60e289) point to this being a conflict with installed shell extensions. They suggest installing http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.zip to disable any third-party addons, and then try restarting to see if it gets fixed.

Failing that, you can cut all your data from these paths:

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations

Then unpin the programs and restart Explorer.