# Windows 7 unable start recent app from taskbar

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, taskbar

When I right click on an opened app in the task bar, the recent used are shown.

For some time now I am not able to run recent when I click on it. The context menu is hidden when I click on recent item.

How to fix this?

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit English.

Comment: What kind of application is this? What is shown when right-clicking is dependent on the application.

Comment: it is Remote desktop protocol application (RDP)

Comment: I believe this is a possible duplicate to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/166178/enable-remote-desktops-recent-connection-list-jump-list)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a system restore to see if you can get this function working to its original capacity? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore

Comment: No I have not tried it.it is like 4 months of system changes, do you think that can help?